# Adding a help link to a SharePoint Online List?

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, help

I'm working on a revamp of our company's current SharePoint site (Using the classic experience) and am wondering if there's a way to add a Help icon to the list which would link the user to a designated wiki page outlining any workflows/processes for that library.

Ideally, this icon would only show once I've added a link to the designated page. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use html to achieve your purpose.

Just add a Content Editor web part to the list which you want to show the icon. Then edit the Content Editor web part to add below code(I have uploaded the icon picture to my library):

```
<a href="http://www.google.com">
<img src="{your site url}/doc1/test.jpg" />
</a>
```

Then save your changes.

[image]